# What is a viewport at a desktop screen and what is visual viewport and layout viewport at a mobile screen

Tags: css

I do not understand what is a viewport at a desktop screen and what is a visual viewport and a layout viewport at a mobile screen. Are these viewports abstract or they are not? I have read a lot of articles about viewports but I don not have a clear understanding of it (just confusing).

Comment: Not exactly a CSS issue, but well. The way I understand viewport: This is the initial screen estate available to display your content. There are means to set scaling/zooming factors; for what it's worth.

Comment: thank you for the unswer